# Unable to pass data to new screen on click

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've a list of news displayed using `card` widget and want to show details of corresponding news in new screen when user taps on any news. However, somehow the data I am trying to pass to new screen is `null` and not sure where the issue is. Error I am getting is:

`The getter 'urlToImage' was called on null.` If I understand this error correctly, the `news` object I am passing is returning `null` but how do I use that object to send actual data using `Navigator` ?

**News model:**

```
class News {
  String title;
  String description;
  String urlToImage;
  String content;

  News(
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.urlToImage,
    this.content
  );
}
```

**Card widget showing image and title of news:**

```
class NewsCard extends StatelessWidget{
final String title, urlToImage;

  News news;

NewsCard({this.title,this.urlToImage});
final makeListTile = ListTile(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Details(news)));
    },
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
    leading: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          right: BorderSide(
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Image(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 50.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(urlToImage),
      ),
    ),
    title: Text(title, style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
    )),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, size: 30.0)
  );
  return
    Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
    elevation: 8.0,
    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
    child: Container(
      child: makeListTile,
    )
    );
}

}
```

`NewsCard` class is called as below:

```
class _NewsClassState extends State<NewsClass> {
  final List<NewsCard> _news = <NewsCard>[];
```

**Details screen**

```
class Details extends StatelessWidget {

  final News news;

  Details(this.news);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News Details'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network('${news.urlToImage}',fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          Container(
            child: Text('${news.content}')
            ),
      ]
          )
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: where you have initialised news object ??

Comment: I've initialized it inside `NewsCard` class as `News news;` . @AjayBeniwal

Comment: News news will not initialize it is just a null pointer News references you have to initalise using new keyword the problem you are getting because you are passing null object to the material page route

Comment: Got it. I am now seeing the data in new screen, although I had to tweak code a bit. @AjayBeniwal